Probability N Points in a Semi Circle
If you have N points on a circle, what is the probability that they are all in a semi-circle?
This question has been answered before, but I have a question about the provided answers.
The answer goes as follows. For each of the N points, treat it as the left-most point of the semi-circle. Then, find the probability each of the other points lies in it, which is $(\frac{1}{2})^{N-1}$. Adding these up,we get $ P = \frac{N}{2^{(N-1)}} $.
My question is, why do we only check the semi-circle in the clockwise direction. For a given point i, why do we not check if the remaining points start in the clockwise or the counterclockwise semi-circle? This should double the probability.

Let $I$ be the indicator variable that all $N$ points lie on any semicircle. Let $I_i$ be the indicator variable that the all $N$ points lie on the clockwise semicircle from point $i$. Then show that $I = \sum I_i$ and that these have distinct support. (IE $I_i I_j = 0 $).
